# JavaScript Date Formatting Ignore Time Zone

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, adonis.js

I am working on a node.js app that is pulling a date from a sql server database, the date comes out of the database correctly, but when processed in the javascript it ends up a day prior. I have tried manually parsing the date, the `date-format` package and `moment.js` all of which take a day off. I initially thought it was time zone related after I tried a datetime variable and it was off by 5 hours. So my theory was that it was incorrectly assuming time zone. However my timezone is EST which is UTC-4 currently.

**Code**

```js
const m = require('moment')
const callDate = m(summary.callDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(summary.callDate)
console.log(callDate)
```

**Output**

```
2019-10-21T00:00:00.000Z
10/20/2019
```

Comment: ...and the input string from the database is?

Comment: Are you planning on only having EST (UTC-4) dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be applies the server timezone by default. So to unify all dates you may want to use `moment.utc(dateObject).format();`